# In Prolog, how to make comparison when order is defined in a chain of predicates?

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure, knowledge-management

Having the following definition:

```
biggerThan(a,b).
biggerThan(b,c).
biggerThan(c,d).
```

How to define a rule `is_bigger(X,Y)`, such that `is_bigger(a,c)` and `is_bigger(a,d)` will return true.

Besides, I am very new to Prolog. Did the title properly addressed the problem, if not, how should I say is?

Comment: Title is ok, but maybe edit 'if' -> 'is'.

Comment: Define `is_bigger/2` recursively. Think about your example of `is_bigger(a,d)`. Why is it true? It's true because `biggerThan(a,b)` is true and recursively `is_bigger(b,d)` is true. The easy case is that `is_bigger(a,b)` is true because `biggerThan(a,b)` is true. I've now done all but write the predicate directly for you. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define `is_bigger` as the transitive closure of the `biggerThan` relation:

```
biggerThan(a,b).
biggerThan(b,c).
biggerThan(c,d).

is_bigger(X, Y) :- biggerThan(X, Y).
is_bigger(X, Y) :- biggerThan(X, Z), is_bigger(Z, Y).
```

The transitive closure of a relation `R` happens to be the smallest relation `X` such that `R` is contained in `X` (this is the first clause of the definition), and such that `X = R o X` (this is the second part). So, the above is basically one possible definition written out.